# Browsing file or directory Dialog in Python

Tags: python, file, browser, directory, tkinter

I'm doing a small project in Python and I would like to browse a file or directory to get their path.

I'm using Tkinter and I was abble to find only a file browser:

```
filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,title='Open file to encrypt')
```

or only a directory browser:

```
dir =  tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root, title='Open file to encrypt')
```

Is it possible to combine these two?
THank you for all the answers!

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not possible to combine them. The file browser and directory browser have different UIs because they are accomplishing different tasks.

Most programs handle this by differentiating the task in their File menu. You might have a "Select File" or "Select Folder" option. This would lead you to either the File browser or the Directory browser.