# Opening a single file or a directory in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a simple way to let the user select either a single file or a directory in tkinter from a common dialog ?
I know there are the `askopenfilename()` and `askdirectory()` methods, but is there a simple way to combine the two ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't think there is...

Comment: I think this question is the duplicate of [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706571/browsing-file-or-directory-dialog-python).